PlatformIO cannot read library for Arduino.H
So i was trying to compile a project from WOKWI to platformIO.
the following error is shown: fatal error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory
i do realize the error was trying to tell me that the library cannot be read. but i didnt know the fix for the error. any suggestion?
this was shown
I was trying to reinstall the library, but it did not work. any fix regarding the error?
